# Rails : how to require files from lib folder in order to use them in controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a specific app folder in my lib/ which contains everything that is not relevant to rails. This is the structure :

`lib/
  |myapp/
    |repositories/
      |repo1.rb
      |repo2.rb
    |use_cases/ 
      |use_case1.rb
      |use_case2.rb`

I added the lib folder in my autoload_path like this :

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

If I want to use UseCase1 in one of my controllers I have to specify the full path :

`MyApp::UseCases::UseCase1.new`

Same thing for repositories.

Is there a way to require it globally so as I can only use UseCase1.new in my controllers ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requiring and including are different. Requiring is the process of loading the file and (making `MyApp::UseCases::UseCase1` available), whereas `include` will mix a module into the current module; this has the effect of making its constants available in the current context, as well.

In an initializer, try explicitly requiring your files:

```
require File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "myapp", "use_cases", "use_case1.rb")
require File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "myapp", "use_cases", "use_case2.rb")
```

Then include the module containing your classes:

```
include MyApp::UseCases
```

This should make all the constants under `UseCases` available for lookup in the current scope, which in the case of an initializer will be the `main` scope, making those constants effectively available everywhere.

Comment: Thanks ! It works great. I use the following code to require all the use_cases : `repositories = File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "myapp", "use_cases", "*.rb")
Dir[File.expand_path(repositories, __FILE__)].each do |file|
  require file
end`. I do not need to configure autoload_path anymore with the whole content of lib/.

Comment: Rails.root is already a Pathname-Object, so

  require Rails.root.join("lib", "myapp", "use_cases", "use_case1.rb")

would be enough.

Since the lib-folder is already part of the LOAD_PATH in rails, a simple require like in any other ruby-application would do the job:

  require "myapp/use_cases/use_case1"